# Fatal Error: Call to member function on non-object when it is an object

Tags: php, class, oop, object, foreach

I have one class that holds an array of Classes. When looping through the array and trying to run Class functions, I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTDs() on a non-object on line 21
```

Here is my code:

**Cars.class**

```
class Cars {
    private $cars = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $result = DB::getData("SELECT * FROM `cars` ORDER BY `name`");

        foreach($result as $row){
            $this->cars[] = new Car($row);
        }
    }

    public function printTable(){
        $html = '<table>';
        for($i=0, $l=count($this->cars); $i<$l; $i++){
            $html .= '<tr>';
            $html .= $this->cars[$i]->getTDs();
            $html .= '<td></td>';
            $i++;
            //print_r($this->cars[$i]);
            //print_r($this->cars[$i]->getTDS());
            $html .= $this->cars[$i]->getTDs(); //This is the supposed non-object
            $html .= '<td></td>';
            $i++;
            $html .= $this->cars[$i]->getTDs();
            $html .= '</tr>';
        }
        $html .= '</table>';
        echo($html);
    }
}
```

**Car.class**

```
class Car {
    public $data;

    public function __construct($data){
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getTDs(){
        $html = '<td>'.$this->data['name'].'</td>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

When using `print_r` on that "non-object" (line 19) I get this:

```
Car Object
(
    [data] => Array
    (
        [name] => 'Ferrari'
    )
)
```

When using `print_r` on the "non-object" calling `getTDs()` (line 20) I get this:

```
<td>Ferrari</td>
```

So how come when in the very next line when I try to add that result to my `$html` variable it breaks?

Comment: When PHP tells you something is not an object it really isn't an object.

Comment: `var_dump($this->cars)` and see if there're more than 1 object in it.

Comment: This is more of a question than an answer but can you create a new instance of the a class with in the same class your are instantiating.  Meaning your `New Car` line?  Can't you just `$this`?

Comment: @u_mulder `var_dump($this->cars)` shows 115 cars. Which is how many I have in my database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for statement is:

```
for($i=0, $l=count($this->cars); $i<$l; $i++){
```

But inside that loop, you are incrementing `$i` twice more.

```
$i++;
$i++;
```

So at the last iteration through the loop, `$i` points to the last element of `cars`, but when you increment `$i` again, you're reaching past the end of the array.

So stop the loop before you reach too far. Your fix should be:

```
for($i=0, $l=count($this->cars)-2; $i<$l; $i++){
```

**Edit** It is smarter to check if you're at the end of the `cars` array every time you attempt to access an index.

Comment: Ah you're right. The error was not on the 2nd object as I had supposed but near the end of the array. Although subtracting 2 from the count isn't the fix, checking if `$i == $l` before each call is. Thanks.

Comment: And if you are at the end of the array, then output `<td></td>` so you're not breaking the last row

Answer (score -1):

You're incrementing your index inside the loop, which you do not need to do. This should work fine:

```
for($i=0, $l=count($this->cars); $i<$l; $i++){
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= $this->cars[$i]->getTDs();
        $html .= '<td></td>';
        $html .= "</tr>";
}
```

Also, as a best practice, try using count outside loops, it has better performance.

```
$numCars = count($this->cars);
for($i=0; $i<$numCars; $i++)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: The count *is* taking place outside the loop, and you've broken the intended layout the OP wanted.

Comment: First part of the `for` loop is for **initialization**, that is, it will be executed only once. So, there's no performance issues. The only difference between these two pieces of code is the scope where `$l` is defined.